# How to catch empty field using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

The input lines:

```
Line1 \t435\tYes           #expected extraction ("", "435", "Yes")
Line2 A1\t222\tYes         #expected extraction ("A1", "222", "Yes")
Line3 A2\t223\tYes         #expected extraction ("A2", "223", "Yes")
```

For my java code,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\t(.*)\\t(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(.....)
```

I need to use the regular expression to fetch each field though lines, and the regular expression works for Line 2 and Line 3. However, I noticed the (.*) would not catch the empty field in Line 1. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tiny tweak:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)\\t(.*)\\t(.*)");
```

This forces the search "from the beginning" so there will be an "empty" match for the "nothing" before the `\t`.

But honestly - if you look at http://regex101.com/r/yH3zG3 it does appear that your expression should work without modification. Is there something else going on in your file? What happens if you switch the order of the lines? What match do you get from line 1?

Comment: You're right. Seems like my input data has other issue. So a "tab" in Line 1 was not read. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Richard - glad I could point you in the right direction. It happens very often that "the problem is not in the code you are showing" - but sometimes that is all you need to hear in order to start searching in the right place. "It is easy to find the needle in the haystack once someone tells you it is really there".